# java scrollpane with flowlayout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, flowlayout

For some reason, I cannot this working. It should be simple really.

I've having a JFrame with a `BorderLayout`, which contains a `JPanel` (SOUTH) and a (CENTER) JPanel (itemPanel).

itemPanel should be wrapped in a scrollpane. Its width = x, and all of its children shares its length, so it basically works like a table with only 1 column.

For some reason, I cannot get the scrollpane to show the scrollbars (and scroll). In the JFrame:

```
setPreferredSize(dimension);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
getContentPane().add("South",controlPanel);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(itemPanel);
scroll.setBorder(null);
getContentPane().add("Center",scroll);
super.pack();
setVisible(true);
```

Initilizing and adding some dummy-panels to the itemPanel:

```
itemPanel = new ItemPanel(); // A JPanel with a flowlayout
itemPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dimension.width,0));
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,50));
  p.setBackground(i%2 == 0 ? Color.GREEN : Color.YELLOW);
  itemPanel.add(p);
}
```

if omitting `itemPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dimension.width,0));` the scrollpane shows the horizontal scrollbars, but since the flowlayout does not have a width to follow, it just shows the components in one row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A FlowLayout does NOT recalculate the preferred size of a panel. The scrollbars only appear when the preferred size of the component is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

[WrapLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, that was easy :) Thanks!

While I dont understand the problem yet, this solved it.